# Emmet autocomplete is not functioning in JSX

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I'm new to Visual Studio Code and trying to get emmet to work on JSX. I read that I had to use the following code in my settings, but it is still not working. Can anyone troubleshoot for me?

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "html": "html",
      "javascript": "javascriptreact",
      "xml": {
        "attr_quotes": "single"
      }
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything from the github issue for this? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4962

Comment: If your JSX files have a JS extension like `home.js` then VSCode is going to interpret them as javascript files and not javascriptreact. For that you have to got to the settings and change the file associations property.

Answer (score 19):

i found out that sometimes Emmet "forgets" to look for HTML in JS files, but it still does work in JSX and CSS files. So I put a few lines to "remind" Emmet look HTML in js files as well, associate with them, here it is:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

or this:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"files.associations": { "*.js": "javascriptreact" }
```

here is the [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43239)

Comment: Thanks mate you made my day. The second option worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "html": "html",
  "javascript": "javascriptreact",
  "xml": {
    "attr_quotes": "single"
  }
},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
```

The only difference to your code is I removed the last curly brace so it is properly contained within the `settings.json` object. If you want these settings to work with all your files and projects make sure the changes are in your `USER SETTINGS`.

[Here is the VSCode related documentation for Emmet configuration.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working even after adding emmet for React in settings in vs code like

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

then try to autocomplete in a HTML file once and now it should work in React.